# How can I check if an animation is finished inside other animation callback function?

Tags: jquery, animation

```
$("#IMAGE1").animate({"left": "+=1050px", queue: false}, "slow", function()
{
   // Want this to happen when the image2 animation is completed as well.
   $("#IMAGE1").css('left', $('#IMAGE2').position().left);
}

$("#IMAGE2").animate({"left": "+=1050px", queue: false}, "slow");
```

How do I check when the image2.animation is finished inside the body of the callback function of image1.animation?

Comment: Why don't you call image2 animation in the callback of animation1

Comment: You've got a syntax error. Your first call to `.animate()` isn't closed. Also, you don't need to re-query the DOM, you can use `$(this)` in your callback.

Comment: @Sushanth-- I'm making a slider, and I need two images to animate at the same time.

Comment: @ahren you make a valid point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `:animated` selector:

```
if ($('#IMAGE1').is(':animated')) {
    // it's animating...
}
```

References:

- [`:animated` selector](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/).

Comment: Are you sure this works? I'm testing it in my jquery slider and I'm alerting image2's x position and its not what im expecting..

Comment: I solved my problem by just resetting the x position to 0 but its kind of cheap in my opinion but it'll suffice for now. Thanks for your effort :)